# Warning: QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, static-libraries, qthread, qtimer

I am seeing this warning message when attempting to run timers inside of my shared library:

`Warning: QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread`

This behavior was not an issue when using a static library. So is this the expected behavior because of the shared library? I am not actively using threads either so I am unsure as to why I am seeing this.

Comment: How do you ensure that your shared library uses the same Qt binary modules as the consumer application? This could be a problem if they are mismatched. Also this warning looks old - what Qt version is it? Side note: if your code runs, it runs in a thread. It’s impossible to run code if it’s not in some thread :)

Comment: I am unsure how I would go about ensuring that, and I am using Qt 5.12.